# Sheet Coming in as undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, undefined, validation

I have a spreadsheet with revenue and expense data. Here is a spreadsheet with what it looks like with data redacted: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xYXt_pvhpzCO7D61SoOwcmNNIGaFHkExwLHhl56c-NU/edit?usp=sharing

I want to create a script that validates the data in column C by forcing a user to enter a date. Once a date is entered, I want to return a new row beneath it. The code works in that it validates data and enters a new row, but when I enter a date into C96, the new row pushes the 'Date' cell, currently in C100, down to C101 and says the date is invalid. I set up my code so that it should be rerunning the script and not making C101 data validated. Additionally, I am getting errors with the 'getRange' method. It is saying that 'TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of undefined.'
Currently I have triggers for onEdit and onOpen for both dateValidation functions and onEdit triggers for the addRow functions.

For some reason, on my original file, the code still runs despite these errors. I have starred the location of the errors in my code below. I am very new to Google Scripts/ programming in general, so if anyone can help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code currently:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("General Ledger");

  // Get row of first revenue
  var firstRowRevLookup = 'Revenue';
  var firstRowRange = sheet.getRange('B1:B');
  var firstRowValues = firstRowRange.getValues();
  var x = [];
  for (var i = 0; i<firstRowValues.length; i++) {
    if(firstRowValues[i] == firstRowRevLookup) {
     x.push(i+3); 
    }
  }
  var firstRowRevenue = Number(x);
  Logger.log(firstRowRevenue);

  //Get row of last revenue
  var lastRowRevLookup = 'End Revenues';
  var lastRowRange = sheet.getRange('C1:C');
  var lastRowValues = lastRowRange.getValues();
  var y = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lastRowValues.length; i++) {
    if(lastRowValues[i] == lastRowRevLookup) {
     y.push(i);
    }
  }
  var lastRowRevenue = Number(y);
  Logger.log(lastRowRevenue)

  //Get row of first expense
  var firstRowExLookup = 'Expenses';
  var z = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<firstRowValues.length; i++) {
    if(firstRowValues[i] == firstRowExLookup){
     z.push(i+3); 
    }
  }
  var firstRowExpense = Number(z);
  Logger.log(firstRowExpense);

  //Get row of last expense
  var lastRowExLookup = 'End Expenses';
  var q = [];
  for(var i = 0; i <lastRowValues.length; i++) {
    if( lastRowValues[i] == lastRowExLookup) {
     q.push(i); 
    }
  }
  var lastRowExpense = Number(q);
  Logger.log(lastRowExpense);

dateValidationExpenses(sheet, firstRowExpense, lastRowExpense);
dateValidationRevenue(sheet, firstRowRevenue, lastRowRevenue);

//User must enter date into column C
function dateValidationExpenses(sheet, firstRowExpense, lastRowExpense) {
 // Logger.log(sheet);
  **var dateRange = sheet.getRange(firstRowExpense, 3, lastRowExpense-firstRowExpense+1);**
  //Logger.log(dateRange);
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
       .requireDate()
       .setAllowInvalid(false)
      .setHelpText('Please enter date using format "=date(year,month,day)"')
      .build();
  dateRange.setDataValidation(rule);
  dateRange.setFontWeight('normal');
}

//User must enter date into column C
function dateValidationRevenue(sheet,firstRowRevenue,lastRowRevenue) {
  **var dateRange = sheet.getRange(firstRowRevenue, 3, lastRowRevenue-firstRowRevenue+1);**
   var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
       .requireDate()
       .setAllowInvalid(false)
       .setHelpText('Please enter a date using format   "=date(year,month,day)"')
       .build();
  dateRange.setDataValidation(rule);
  dateRange.setFontWeight('normal');
}

function addRowExpenses () {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('General Ledger');
  var testCell = sheet.getRange(lastRowExpense,3).getValue();
  //Logger.log(testCell);
  if (testCell !== '') {
  sheet.insertRows(lastRowExpense+1);
  }

}

function addRowRevenue () {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('General Ledger');
  var testCell = sheet.getRange(lastRowRevenue,3).getValue();
  //Logger.log(testCell);
  if (testCell !== '') {
  sheet.insertRows(lastRowRevenue+1);
  }
}

function editTrigger1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('addRowExpenses')
      .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}

function editTrigger2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('addRowRevenue')
      .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}
```

Comment: I see that in the sample script you are calling the sheet by name as "General Ledger", but the sheet name in the example spreadsheet shows as 'Sheet 1'. Make sure both of them having the same name.

Comment: On my original file, it is called 'General Ledger'. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

The variable `sheet` is declared outside of a function, which makes it a "global".  You don't need to pass `sheet`

Currently:

```
dateValidationExpenses(sheet, firstRowExpense, lastRowExpense);
dateValidationRevenue(sheet, firstRowRevenue, lastRowRevenue);
```

Change to:

```
dateValidationExpenses(firstRowExpense, lastRowExpense);
dateValidationRevenue(firstRowRevenue, lastRowRevenue);
```

`sheet` is available to the `dateValidationExpenses` function without the need to pass it.  That should solve the issue with the error you are getting on this line:

```
var dateRange = sheet.getRange(firstRowExpense, 3, lastRowExpense-firstRowExpense+1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The firstRowExpense, firstRowRevenue, lastRowExpense, and lastRowRevenue variables are also global.
When I declare and call the function, should I also not pass them as parameters then?

Comment: When I remove all parameters when calling and defining the functions, the errors go away. However, I am still having the problem of the 'Date' cell in C100 becoming invalid when I enter a date into C96 and a new row is entered. Any advice on this?

Comment: don't use a global for those. get cells from sheet just before you need them.